# Flex items overflowing container in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

My flex container has a horizontal list of items which all browsers display properly inside their parent except IE11, that seems incapable of keeping them within it, instead they "bleed out" of it, like so:

[image]

Below is a simplified [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pgxk3c7/8/) of my setup which demonstrates the problem in action:

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Result on Chrome:
[image]

Result on IE11:
[image]

Any workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like IE11 requires you to define a size for the flex items (`li`):

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
 
li {              /* NEW */
  flex: 0 1 100%; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
  /* flex: 1 */   /* alternatively, this also works (short for: fg:1, fs:1, fb:0px) */
}

li img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8pgxk3c7/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, is the the correct approach or not, but you can try this hack, it works

you may also try this using `modernizr` to target `IE`browsers

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

_:-ms-fullscreen .ie-hack li,
:root .ie-hack li {
  display: flex;
}

li img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ie-hack">
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" width="50" height="50" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, IE11 wants child flex items to have a width set.  Your markup shows that you are trying to set a height and width on the image. You could take off those height and width attributes in the image, and then just have your image set to `width: 100%`. This will allow each image to take up the space of its parent, and still scale based on how many are in the container.

Alternatively, if you don't want those images to get larger, you could set a `max-width` on the `li`

```css
ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
 
li {              

 flex-grow: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;
 /* max-width: 50px; for keeping image from ever getting larger than certain point */
}

li img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png"  alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png"  alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png"  alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/60PVLis.png"  alt=""></li>
</ul>
```